# Can a NSObject be the delegate of two instances of a class?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have two NSTextfield, and I want to use the same method for each one:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange: (id)sender {
[label setStringValue:[textfield stringValue]];
}
```

I would like to use a different `label/textfield` couple depending on which NSTextField send the message. Is this information available in the `sender` object, or do I have to create a new delegate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[sender object]` is your `textfield`, so getting the `stringValue` is easy. Getting the associated label, however, is not: you need to build your own scheme to find it.

One way could be by marking your text fields by setting their `tag` properties to different numbers. If you set the tag of text field for the first label to 1 and the tag of text field for the second label to 2, you can do something like this:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange: (id)sender {
    NSTextField *textfield = [sender object];
    NSLabel *label = nil;
    switch ([textfield tag]) {
    case 1: label = myLabelOne; break;
    case 2: label = myLabelTwo; break;
    }
    [label setStringValue:[textfield stringValue]];
}
```

Comment: For `[sender tag]`, the runtime outputs this: `-[NSConcreteNotification tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9a516dc080`. Is `sender` really the object that sent the message to the delegate ?

Comment: @Antoine No, I was wrong, it's `NSNotification`. Unless I'm mistaken again, you should be able to pull the text field from it by calling `[sender object]`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange: (id)sender {
    [[[window contentView]
    viewWithTag:( [[sender object] tag] + 100 )]
    setStringValue:[ [sender object] stringValue]];
```

I set in interface builder the tag of the labels to a value of: 100 + the tag of the associated NSTextField. There is also no need for IBOutlet.

Comment: Giving labels `tag+100` works too! No matter what tagging scheme you choose, the trick is to pull the tag from the sender, and use it to look up the counterpart component one way or the other: I used a `switch`, you used `viewWithTag`. Either way, you can reuse your delegate for as many objects as you'd like.